# VBA Javascript logout dialog box removal

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am using Excel VBA and on a website when I want to logout it pops up a dialog box that says are you sure you want to exit. In order to automate the process I would like for it to be bypassed or hit the OK option. Looking through the code I see that the exit function correlates to `<a href=javascript:logout()`. When I execute this link via VBA it pauses the code and pops up the dialog box and will not let the Macro proceed until I have selected OK or Cancel. Can I put something between the parenthesis that will allow me to just state that I want it to automatically select OK? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look deeper into the source of that `javascript:logout()` function and you should be able to find the companion function that runs the actual log out routine when a positive confirmation is met. Assuming that you are using an Internet.Explorer object to scrape that URl you can then run the companion function directly with something like,

```
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:Really_Log_Out();"
```

You haven't provided much in the way of specifics but perhaps you can transcribe that for your own purposes.